# How to resolve ApiLambdaFunction error using serverless to deploy Angular app to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am trying to deploy my Angular app to AWS using the [serverless](https://github.com/serverless/serverless) package, following the steps in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-6LtzJezsk) tutorial.

I've followed the steps correctly, & ran `npm run build:serverless:deploy`, but rather than the app being successfully deployed I get the following error message in the console:

> An error occurred: ApiLambdaFunction -
>   The runtime parameter of
>   nodejs6.10 is no longer supported for creating or updating AWS Lambda
>   functions. We recommend you use the new runtime (nodejs10.x) while
>   creating or updating functions. (Service: AWSLambdaInternal; Status
>   Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID:
>   dba0ade8-1f2c-4dc7-8ddc-c2966a54a67c).

When I run `node -v` in my command line, I see that it's version 10.14.1.

However, I did find the following `nodejs6.10` reference in `serverless.yml`:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs6.10
  memorySize: 192
  timeout: 10
  stage: production
  region: eu-central-1
```

Can someone please tell me why this is occurring & how to resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it happens is that you are trying to set the Node.js version running in your Lambda function to Node.js 6 and this is no longer supported.

Change your `serverless.yml` file to

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  memorySize: 192
  timeout: 10
  stage: production
  region: eu-central-1
```

The error message is pretty clear though. AWS has discontinued the support for Node.js 6 one or two months ago. Only functions that were originally created in this version will still work. New functions can no longer be created in Node.js 6. Honestly, there isn't a single reason somebody would want to do it anyways.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/node-js-6-is-approaching-end-of-life-upgrade-your-aws-lambda-functions-to-the-node-js-10-lts/